# what is difference in deportation and VRS

Tags: visas, uk

one of my friend travel to UK and was done 12 month prison and he availed voluntary return scheme can he go back to UK again or not.

Comment: What is his nationality? He may be ineligible to enter under V9.1.2 not conducive to the public good; voluntary departure is a one-year ban https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/606970/GI-Re-entry-bans-v7.pdf#page5

Comment: Was he deported? What was his actual sentence length? He cannot enter the UK for at least 15 years since the end of his sentence. 12months-4 years in prison means a 15 year bar. Depending on the crime, entry could be refused at the officer's discretion for longer.